# Does rostopic use message broker between nodes?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Do nodes in ROS send/receive messages through a message broker or are TCP/UDP packets sent directly between the publishing and subscribing nodes? I don't see such a broker mentioned in the ROS "concepts" doc but the "hello robot" messaging example seems to imply the existence of a broker because the hello message is stored somewhere for echoing before a subscriber is online. If there is indeed a message broker in the middle of the communication path, is the Master node that broker?

Thanks,

yc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279796/does-rostopic-use-message-broker-between-nodes?/) by [yclab1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33280/yclab1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The data communications over a topic are direct without a broker. There is a master which helps nodes connect to each other. Please see the technical overview here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Example

If you edit your question to point to what example you're referring to I or someone else could provide more information about that context.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yclab1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33280/yclab1/) on 2018-01-15**:
Thanks for you answer! I should have continued reading to the end of the "ROS/Concepts" instead of being befuddled by the "rostopic echo" command in "Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics". Your answer clarified it. Thanks!